# How to select (mark) the body of a C function in emacs?

Tags: emacs, c-mode

I used to remember a key combination in c-mode to select a C function (i mean select the text between start and end of function for copying/killing etc) but i've since forgotten it and can't seem to find it anywhere. Does anyone remember what this key combination is?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Emacs 23, it appears to be bound to:

```
C-M-h           c-mark-function
```

FWIW, I found this by listing all the commands for the mode `C-h b`, and searching for 'mark'.

Comment: thanks! im not yet so proficient with the emacs help system, but ill work on it :)

Comment: It's all a learning process, that's why I added *how* I got the answer - the whole give a man a fish or teach him how.

Comment: This is really helpful, I just use `C-h b` and figured out how to mark a function in `Pyhon mode`.